# How to verify video card driver certificate?

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, gpu

How i can from program (C++ WinApi) verify video card driver. I need to check is driver is official version of ATI,NVIDIA,Intel driver. To exclude other custom driver versions and prevent program exceptions. Thanks!

Comment: If what you're looking for is to just to see if a driver is valid and official (without code), you could find the vendor code in the properties and check with: http://www.pcidatabase.com

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What will your program do if someone is using an incorrect driver? I work with writing drivers, mostly for GPU's. I have done that for years. It takes A LOT of effort to test a driver to for example WHQL standard. So, if someone (who may be using your program) finds a bug in a driver, they may well want that bug fixed "this week", not in 6 months time. Hence, they will be given an unofficial driver version. Note that quality assured drivers are only guaranteed to work under conditions tested. I have found/fixed bugs found by "strange" apps more than once.

Comment: I use OpenCL for do math in my program, and i need to know, that nobody can steal my openCL code by using custom driver, because opencl code is critical for sell program. So i need to protect this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`WinVerifyTrust`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and according to the linked documentation this function is able to inform your program about the fact that a given driver is a *Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL) signed driver* or not.